# Keyword arguments for Rust macro

Tags: rust, macros

Suppose I have a struct like this:

```rust
struct Foo {
  a: i32,
  b: i32,
}
```

Is it possible to define a macro using `macro_rules` such that I can create `Foo`s like this?

```rust
let f1 = make_foo!(
  a=5,
);
let f2 = make_foo!(
  b=2,
  a=6,
);
let f3 = make_foo!(
  b=9,
);
let f4 = make_foo!();
```

I want all the arguments to be optional - I'll specify a default in the macro or via the `Default` trait - and ideally the order not to matter though that's just "nice to have".

Answer (score 2):

This is possible to do using the Field Record Update syntax:

```
#[derive(Debug, Default)]
struct Foo {
    a: i32,
    b: i32,
}

macro_rules! make_foo {
    ($($field:ident = $value:expr),* $(,)?) => {
        Foo {
            $(
                $field: $value,
            )*
            ..Default::default()
        }
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0bca4b19b132662e858f0c62e8e4c554)

Comment: Amazing! Is there any way to do different things for different fields? E.g. if I want one field to do `$value.to_string()`?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, sorry.

Comment: I found a way - see my answer. Couldn't have done it without yours though, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To follow up on Cerberus's answer, if you want to do per-field handling of the values passed you can add a module with functions that match the field names, like this:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Default)]
pub struct Foo {
    a: i32,
    b: String,
}

mod foo_setters {
    pub fn a(x: i32) -> i32 { x }
    pub fn b(x: &str) -> String { x.to_owned() }
}

macro_rules! make_foo {
    ($($field:ident = $value:expr),* $(,)?) => {
        Foo {
            $(
                $field: foo_setters::$field($value),
            )*
            ..Default::default()
        }
    }
}

pub fn foo() -> Foo {
    make_foo!(
        a = 5,
        b = "hi", // No need for .to_string()!
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The tricky part would be finding out which fields exist. It might be possible to write a proc macro that does this, but I would recommend another approach.

The idiomatic way in Rust is to use the Builder pattern. And there's a crate that writes these builders automatically for your: https://docs.rs/derive_builder/0.10.2/derive_builder/

This one exists too: https://crates.io/crates/typed-builder

Comment: Yeah that's probably my backup option. I'm going to have to write this a lot though so was trying to go with something as terse as possible.